# Angular 4: Recreive data from MySQL to array

Tags: mysql, ajax, angular, request

I have been learning Angular and I made simple app which use database request and print all information from MySQL. In my service I made this method

```
  getCharacters(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost/something/controller/characters')
              .map(
                (response: Response) => {
                  return response.json();
                }
              );
  }
```

In characters-list component I used subscribe()

```
this.charactersService.getCharacters().subscribe(
  (characters) => {
    this.characters = characters;
  }
);
```

It works of course but it's not practical. I want to use one array to a few components so I would retrieve data from MySQL one time and use this array in all components I want to.

How to do that?

Comment: Look into "service". That might be useful.

Comment: esponse.json() ?

Comment: Response :) I miss one letter but in oryginal code it was correctly. So it's not solve my problem.